# What is an analogue of MKLocalSearch in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an app for two plaforms: iOS and Android. The app must show a map and allow searching for places by partial natural language queries.

For instance, if user begin typing "Airp..." it must return a list of airports nearby.

In iOS I am using `MKMapView` and `MKLocalSearch`.

In Android I am using `GoogleMap`. What is an analogue of `MKLocalSearch` in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides a [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) for place search.

And you can combine the search results with your google map to display them.